# Build on openshift with a Jenkins pipeline referring to a git branch

Tags: git, jenkins, openshift, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following structure:

- a git(gitlab) repository where I have 2 branch (dev and master) (more are there but I'm interested only in this two for the build)
- configurated gitLab that makes a webhook when push/merge action are maded on this project. The webhook points on a pipeline
- a openshift container that has a pod with jenkins installed
- 2 pipeline defined in the openshift jenkins project, one to build the dev branch and one to build the master branch. The pieline are written in groovy, and made some git, maven and oc commands

Versions:

- gitlab 10.1
- openshift 3.4
- Jenkins 2.19.3

What I'm able to do:
make a push on dev/master that start the 2 pipelines and builds the two branches. There starts two build because I don't know how to filter out that a push/merge event is made on dev or master. 
I want to do this because:

- on the build there are some integration tests that use a DB and If the pipeline starts simultaneously then they make some disaster on the test-db
- and there is no reason that the two pipelines starts, when the branch that they represent are not involved. Only the pipeline with the correct branch has to start

I saw two option to resolve this.
On Gitlab there are no possibility to drive the webhook event on a defined branch. (or is there and I don't know how?)
On the pipeline I could write some code to check on witch branch there is made a push/merge. But I don't know how exactly make this check.

Are there other options? 
If possible I don't want to change the workflow, but I'm open to hear any good Idea.

If I'm missing some relevant information please ask me. I don't publish any code because the context are very big, and principally I only need the right direction or some ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

So At the end I found a way by myself.

I think it's not elegant but at the moment it solves my problem.

All I do is to check with git in the pipeline the hash of the last Merge and the last hash of the branch in this way:

```
def lastMerge = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git show :/^Merge --pretty=format:"%H"').trim()  
def hash = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 origin/master --pretty=format:"%H"').trim() 
if(lastMerge==hash){
    doTheJob()
}
```

If there are better solutions, I'm open to hear it.